# detecting packets at a certain port

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy, wireshark

This the python script for my proxy web server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from socket import *

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind(('', 5000))
sockobj.listen(10)

while True:
    conn_sock, client_address = sockobj.accept()
    print('client connected')
    while True:
        message = conn_sock.recv(24000)
        if not message: break
        print("message received")
        print("The sent message is: ", message.decode())
```

I directed my browser's proxy server to localhost: 127.0.0.1 at this port number 5000. I wanted to capture packets at this port no. 5000, so I used wireshark but the packets at 5000 show nothing, is there something wrong with the way I'm using the filter. And as a side question, the message.decode() prints an error, what do you think is the encoding in message?
[image]

Comment: I see from your image that you are using wireshark as packet sniffer. Wireshark in windows can be funny about detecting anything on 127.0.0.1  https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback  As that link suggests, you can use rawcap which is command line and quite simple, let that listen and make a file, and then import that file into wireshark

Comment: also, is your port bound on 127.0.0.1, the host LAN IP, or 0.0.0.0? You can tell in linux with `netstat -ntlup`, and with powershell with `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING`. both platforms require the command to be run as admin.

Comment: @barlop , I'm on ubuntu

Comment: @FrankThomas , I don't know much about it, but I suppose the host LAN IP(That I don't know what it means) is 192.168.1.2? I did check with that as well but, wireshark doesn't respond.

Comment: @barlop, it's only on windows ? It should'd worked on ubuntu right?

Comment: @barlop , rawcap's for windows only?

Comment: @FrankThomas , I 'm on ubuntu , And do you know anything about the encoding issue?

Comment: @barlop , do you know anything about the encoding issue?

Comment: @FrankThomas You wrote "both platforms require the command to be run as admin"  <--- `-b` in windows netstat is totally unnecessary, and without it you don't need admin. -b adds one small convenience and 2 or 3 inconveniences(speed, admin requirement, and knowing that the process name will be coming after the row - which isn't intuitive). You can use netstat -aon and use task manager to see the PID, and -b slows down netstat a lot.

Comment: @mathmaniage I don't think wireshark has a problem with 127.0.0.1 on *nix

Comment: @mathmaniage you could do some troubleshooting eg try `nc -l 5000` then nc `127.0.0.1 5000`  and see if wireshark picks it up

Comment: @mathmaniage yeah rawcap is only for windows you won't need it on linux, wireshark on linux is fine. I suggest you do that test with nc to test wireshark though just to make sure your it is working

Comment: @barlop, : wireshark didn't listen, https://pasteboard.co/Hesuc0N.jpg

Comment: What is the error that message.decode() is emitting? Yes, the LAN IP is probably the 192.168.x.y address. when you bind a port to an interface and its IP(s), that affects the visibility of the port. ports on 127.x.y.z are inaccessible to remote systems,whereas ports bound on a specific IP (like the LAN IP) are accessible to any system that can reach the nic with that IP, and ports bound to 0.0.0.0 are accessible on any nic on the system. Since your port is on a LAN IP, you need to test it with a remote system on the LAN, and make sure wireshark is listening on that nic.

Comment: @barlop, yeah, I've used that lick of powershell as a default for years in a wide range of scenarios where i need to inspect listening ports on a server. often its because I want to see what server software is running on that box, so printing the process name is pretty crucial. it is not necessary in this case, as you point out, since we are already looking for a single known port.

Comment: @FrankThomas  it's never "necessary" to list process name in the windows cmd netstat  listing, as -o lists PID and you can check the process name with task manager.

Comment: ok, but it would be foolish to not use it when trying to find out what 16 pieces of software are establishing listeners. for one or two, I agree, we can do without, but no point in making the job 16 manual steps longer.  I'm not quite sure why you are so anti this option, when it is called for.

Answer (score 0):

I found success by selecting "Adapter for loopback traffic capture" before starting the capture.